# WebAPI store variables for specific user

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've build a simple intranet application using ASP.NET MVC4 that allows users inside network to view some resources. Application is build mostly in ExtJS and WebAPI controllers.
My authorization is based on Active Directory.

Debugging my code I noticed that I'm doing AD calls multiple times.
Here is my AD helper class:

```
public class AD
{
    public static string CurrentUser = "";

    public static string GetCurrentUserLogin()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
    }

    public static Employee GetCurrentUser()
    {
        var login = CurrentUser == "" ? GetCurrentUserLogin() : CurrentUser ;
        return GetUser(login);
    }

    public static Employee GetCurrentUser(string login)
    {
        return GetUser(login);
    }

    public static Employee GetUser(Guid guid)
    {
        using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://wawa.firma.pl/OU=IT,DC=wawa,DC=firma,DC=pl", @"AD_client", "xyzabc"))
        {
            using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
            {
                byte[] bytes = guid.ToByteArray();

                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (byte b in bytes)
                {
                    sb.Append(string.Format(@"\{0}", b.ToString("X2")));
                }
                searcher.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectClass=User)(objectCategory=Person)(objectguid={0}))", sb);
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("description");
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectguid");
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("SN");
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName");
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("manager");
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("telephoneNumber");
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("directReports");
                searcher.SizeLimit = 1;
                searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
                try
                {
                    SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();
                    if (result == null) return null;

                    var emp = ParseSearchResult(result);
                    emp.fullAccess = true;
                    return emp;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine, but every time I must get current user id and I do call like this:

```
var user_id = AD.GetCurrentUser().Id;
```

My problem is that every time I request some property for user that is stored in AD i must do new AD call.
Ideally I would like to do simple call once (for current user) and store it, then every time I need something I will get it from local object.

I read some articles about session in WebAPI controllers, for example: http://stick2basic.wordpress.com/2013/04/18/how-to-access-session-in-web-api-controller-in-mvc4/, but I found also greate example of using Cache: https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache

But Session is per User and Cache per Application.

What would be best way of storing ActiveDirectory results per User? How should I modify my AD class to hold those variables.

The easiest way would be to store result in session as so:

```
public static Employee GetUser(Guid guid)
{
    var e = HttpContext.Current.Session[guid.ToString()] as Employee;
    if (e == null)
    {
        //get user from AD
        //store in session
    }
    return e;
}
```

This way I'll be able to query AD only once, but I won't be able to requery every n-minutes (cache has timeout).

How can I make this easier/better? Are there other ways to do this?

Comment: You can cache it forever using `Dictionary<string, Employee>` should be more than sufficient data structure. Or you can use `System.Runtime.Caching` to cache the value with a TTL.

Comment: @Seph - I want to hold if for 30 minutes, because sometimes AD object can be changed (privileges for example) and I would like to load those updates after some time. Session is per User, but with Dictionary<string, Employee> I could store every employee in cache, because they will have unique guid's. So having cache object with that dictionary can I refresh only specific Employees?  I can set expiration for whole Cached object, but can I do the same for that Dictionary element?

Comment: in that cause use `System.Runtime.Caching` as @oeoren explains further.

Answer (score 0):

You need some memory cache. Have a look at: [MemoryCache Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx)

Store the DirectoryEntry object in the cache with the path as key.